# Java date issues in linux

Tags: java, linux

OK, very bizarre issue here, can't seem to find much on it searching through here or in google.

I have a bot running on an IRC channel. Initially, I run it from my home PC (Windows) and it worked with no issues.
Now I have moved it to a VPS (Linux) and find that it's not reporting dates correctly.

The VPS has the date set correctly:

```
bot@vps:~/bot$ date
Fri Jun 24 13:05:23 WST 2011
```

The bot has two time functions, one simply returns the time and one is a reminder system.
Both use System.currentTimeMillis(). Both report the time wrong;

```
[13:10:00] ( mynick) !time
[13:10:00] ( botnick) mynick: The time is now Thu Jun 23 21:10:00
                 GMT-08:00 2011
```

or:

```
[13:20:19] ( mynick) remind me in 1 minute test
[13:20:19] ( botnick) bmynick: Okay, I'll remind you about that on Thu Jun
                 23 21:21:19 GMT-08:00 2011
```

So it seems it's finding the system time as GMT-8, but I have no idea why? Any suggestions?

Edit: Forced the Java time zone and it now reports correctly, so it seems to be something to do with the JVM

Comment: That's actually fairly typical when running a JVM on Linux or Unix.   There's nothing wrong with System.currentTimeMillis(), it is the formatting code that needs the time zone set properly.

See Suraj's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the JVM is not successfully detecting your system timezone.

I have heard a little about this before, but thought they were all fixed. What java version are you using. There is a detailed explanation of this problem [here](http://www.minaret.biz/tips/timezone.html).

To manually set the timezone you can try these options:

1. Export TZ variable: export TZ="US/Eastern"
2. TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"))
3. java -Duser.timezone=US/Eastern CLASS_NAME

Comment: Exactly right.  Some JVMs won't pick up the default time zone on some Linux distros.   I prefer to specify it explicitly (Method #1) for server-side Java apps.